# listoffigures. How to skip figure numbers?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I only want caption-text and page-number in my `\listoffigures`. What is the best way to do this? The reason is that I do not use chapter/section numbers in the text, and not figure numbers either. I use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}` and `\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}`, respectively to achieve this, which works fine, except the `\listoffigures` gives figure numbers 0.1, 0.2 etc. Thanks ahead!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{-30pt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{subfig}  
%
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}} % New
%
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{1in}
        \hfill\vspace{1in}
    \end{minipage}
    }
\caption{Caption}   
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{1in}
        \hfill\vspace{1in}
    \end{minipage}
    }
\caption{Caption}   
\end{figure}
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: the default would not use `:` in figure counters so you have customised this in code not shown which makes it hard to help. It may be enough to have `\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}` but it may not, it is impossible to say.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If David's suggestion doesn't work, please provide a small complete document, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that exemplifies your problem. We need to see your settings, document class etc in order to propose a suitable solution.

Comment: Thank you both! David's suggestion removed the "0." in front of the figure number such that "0.1" became "1" which certainly looks better but I would prefer to remove the number all together. If a small complete document is needed for a complete description I will do that tomorrow (did not expect such a prompt answer).

Comment: Good morning! I have added a relatively small document. Again, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight alteration to your MWE (for which thank you) that does what you want.

```
% tocfigprob.tex  SE 577194

\documentclass[a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{-30pt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{subfig}  
%
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}} % New
%
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{1in}
        \hfill\vspace{1in}
    \end{minipage}
    }
\caption{Caption 1}   
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{1in}
        \hfill\vspace{1in}
    \end{minipage}
    }
\caption[]{Caption 2}  %% revised
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{Caption 2}  %% new
\end{figure}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% revising \caption

\chapter{Two}

\let\oldcaption\caption
\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{%
  \oldcaption[]{#1}
  \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{#1}
}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{1in}
        \hfill\vspace{1in}
    \end{minipage}
    }
\caption{Caption 1}   
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{1in}
        \hfill\vspace{1in}
    \end{minipage}
    }
\caption{Caption 2}  %% revised
%\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{Caption 2}  %% new
\end{figure}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% end of revision

\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Look at the difference between the two captions.

**EDIT**

I extended my MWE (but not the result) to show that you could change the `\caption` definition so that you did not have to change calling your `\caption` and including the `\addcontentsline`.

This will work if you don't have any `table` floats because if you do their captions will be added to the LoF. I've done the best I can with the information you supplied.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Peter! It does mean that I need to change every caption, right?

Comment: @Olaf se my extended answer.